# How to update the value of a key field in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary as given below:

```
test = {"100":271,"updated_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"},"created_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"}}
```

I have written below program to retrieve keys from the dictionary:

```
test = {"100":271,"updated_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"},"created_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"}}

for keys in test.keys():
    print(keys)
```

I want to update the keys field value when we got a digit value in keys field. Example in the above dictionary

```
keys: 100
value: 271
```

When we got keys value is an integer then I want to updates keys value like this **xx_100:271**

I would like to solve the problem in the simplest way possible using python.

Comment: You can do `test[key] = value` in order to set the value for a particular key. If the key is present, value is updated. Else it is added.

Comment: @pradeep Answer was updated according to the expected output.

Comment: @pradeep: If any one or more than one answers helped you please upvote them and accept one of them!!

Comment: Yes bcoz in your question you asked to change key value from `100` to `xx_100`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> test = {"100":271,"updated_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"},"created_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"}}

>>> dict(("xx_{}".format(k),v) if isinstance(v,int) else (k,v) for k,v in test.items())
{'xx_100': 271, 'updated_at': {'date': '2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z'}, 'created_at': {'date': '2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z'}}
```

Comment: OP need like this `xx_100:271` you  need to modify your answer little bit

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I have gone through your solutions but its changing string key field as well

Comment: @shaikmoeed Its working for a dictionary but its failed with a nested dictionary

Comment: @pradeep If it solved your current question, accept the answer. You can ask more clearly about nested dictionary, if you face any problem while solving. Thanks. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
test = {"100":271,"updated_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"},"created_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"}}
for key in test.keys():
    try:
        if type(key)==int:
            test['xx_'+str(key)]=test.pop(key)
    except: pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = {"100":271,"updated_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"},"created_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"}}

for keys in test.keys():

if isinstance(test[keys], int):
    test[keys] = "xx_" + str(test[keys])

 print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping just `keys`, you need to loop both `key` and `value` to test which value is of type `int`. Below code does that:

```
test = {"100":271,"updated_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"},"created_at":{"date":"2017-10-14T12:15:52.172Z"}}

for key,value in test.items():
    if (type(value)) == int:
        test['xx_'+str(key)]=test.pop(key)
```